# what is the root of classpath for a java web application

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to display some messages from properties file while user enter some incorrect information and submit the form, but I always got warning message from eclipse console like this:

```
WARNING: ResourceBundle [messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name messages, locale en_US
Nov 15, 2017 9:32:42 AM org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource getResourceBundle
```

I config the MessageSource bean in WebConfig.java like this:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource()
{
    ResourceBundleMessageSource validationSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    validationSource.setBasename("messages");
    return validationSource;
}
```

I put my message.properties like below:

[image]

when I right click on the properties file, it shows its path like this:

[image]

so, where is the correct place I should put this properties file? which path is the root of classpath in a java web application?

Answer (score 1):

Currently `src` is your root classpath.

You may want to create another "resources" folder and add it to your classpath.
Then move your property file in it.

[image: classpath]

Above is the usual directory layout for a Maven project.